# testing content of a webpage

Tags: testing, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am new to software testing and was wondering which is the correct way to test content of a web page. For ex. on a web page if there are 10 labels then should I test first header "Selenium Training and Video Tutorials" and then second details given below the header then further details in this way and create separate test step for testing different text? Or I can use div tag which will give me the complete content of the page at once and test everything in one step. I can do it in one step or divide into steps but I want to do it in a correct way. I am using selenium webdriver (java).

Comment: Split it up. Make your tests readable and understandable. Make it so that someone new, to not only the profession but your company, can understand these tests. That's part of your end goal.

Comment: @Arran - you should post that as an answer; it's definitely the right advice.

Comment: Thanks Arran. I did split it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to the arran answer, it is better to split the 10 labels into 10 assert statements so that you can easily know which one went wrong, and also use [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html) or [Junit](http://junit.org/) for assertions. Since you are new, there are methods in TestNG like
[`assertEquals(char actual, char expected)`](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/Assert.html);

So in your code, it might look like

```
header1="programatically get the value using selenium"

assertEquals("Selenium Training and Video Tutorials", header1)
```

Testng also gives you clear report too.

Answer (score 1):

Writing separate tests for each label as described by you will be a great option for :

- increasing understandability
- tracking down any errors
- fixing of the script (if required in future)